# How to pass all values of a field to a sub-report as a parameter in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I've come across several similar questions but none of them are helping me.

Let me explain:

I have a report. Inside this report I have a sub-report.

The sub-report is supposed to take multi-value parameters for all 3 of its parameters.

If I run the sub-report manually, it's working:

[image]

This is how I have the dataset for this sub-report:

[image]

[image]

**And this is how I have my MAIN report:**

[image]

My question is -

How do change the expression from the MAIN report above so that ALL values for that field (AccountName in this case) are being passed to the sub-report AS PARAMETERS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I did but leaving it as

```
=Fields!LocationState.Value
```

worked because the main report had a repeater.

So I was passing to the sub-report the values from a query in the main report based on the repeater groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LookupSet function.

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!FieldYouWishToJoin.Value,"YourDataSetName"),",")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks bro i am searching this from many days you made my day, learn something new LookUpSet